# Whats the difference between a Conceptual Data Model and an ER Diagram?

Tags: database-design

I know the difference between a Conceptual Data Model and a Logical Data Model, but what is the difference between a Conceptual Data Model and an ER diagram? They look extremely similar! Is there any difference?

Comment: This question doesn't really have anything to do with programming, and would probably be better-served on http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: An ER diagram is just a picture of a model using some form of ER notation. That could be a "conceptual" model or a "logical" model (those names in any case may be used quite differently by different people).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ERD` (*Entity-Relatinship-Diagram*) is one of the method in `Conceptual Data Modeling` in order to flesh out in visual form the user requirements whether explicit or implicit in nature. Other method used also in `Conceptual Data Modeling` is the `NIAM` (*Natural language Information Analysis Method*) which is primarily used in Europe and use different symbols compared to `ERD` Modeling. Obviously, `ERD` is more popular hence the one you normally see as the modeling method in `Conceptual Data Modeling` level.

See this [link](http://www.orm.net/pdf/springer.pdf) and this [link](http://essentialstrategies.com/publications/modeling/niam.htm) also.

Answer (score 0):

The three types of datamodels are
Conceptual model: describes data at a very high level such as the ER model

Representational model : describes the logical part of the database such ad Relational model

Physical data model :describes data storage information and is used to generate DDL statments